# How to "remove duplicates" from a UNION query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySQL: One called `gtfsws_users` which contains users for a system I'm developing and another called `gtfsws_repository_users` which contains roles for these users.

`gtfsws_users` has these fields: **email**, **password**, **name**, **is_admin** and **enabled**.
`gtfsws_repository_users` has: **user_email**, **repository_id** and **role**.

The `role` is an integer that defines privileges over a GTFS repository (public transportation data, not relevant for my problem).

One important thing is that **every administrator accont** (that is, every user that has the `is_admin` flag set as `1` in `gtfsws_users`) has full access to all repositories.

Now, only users registered in `gtfsws_repository_users` will have access to a specific repository defined there (unless they are administrators, of course). One user can have multiple repositories which him/her can access.

What I'm trying to do is to get **all users with access to a specific repository** (it doesn't matter which type of `role` the user has, I just want to know if they can access the repository or not). So I'm writing this SQL statement for getting them:

```
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        gtfsws_users.email AS email,
        gtfsws_users.name AS name,
        gtfsws_users.is_admin AS is_admin,
        gtfsws_users.enabled AS enabled,
        gtfsws_repository_users.role AS role
    FROM
        gtfsws_users
    INNER JOIN
        gtfsws_repository_users
    ON
        gtfsws_users.email = gtfsws_repository_users.user_email
    WHERE
        gtfsws_repository_users.repository_id = '2'
)
UNION
(
    SELECT
        email,
        name,
        is_admin,
        enabled,
        null AS role
    FROM
        gtfsws_users
    WHERE
        is_admin = 1
)
```

Now, this works fine for users with access to different repositories. It also gets all administrators too.

The problem is when I have an administrator that is also registered in `gtfsws_repository_users`, because I get it duplicated.

So for example, it I have this in `gtfsws_users`:

`('test@test.com', '*****', 'Real name', 1, 1)`

And also the user is registered in `gtfsws_repository_users` as this:

`('test@test.com', 2, 10)`

When I do the `SELECT` in MySQL (using the `UNION` to add all administrators) I get:

```
('test@test.com', 'Real name', 1, 1, 10)
('test@test.com', 'Real name', 1, 1, NULL)
```

What I need to do is to **filter** that table to remove duplicates, that is getting only:

```
('test@test.com', 'Real name', 1, 1, NULL)
```

Yes, getting `NULL` as the role (since it will be ignored as the user is an administrator).

Does anybody have a clue on how to achieve that?
Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**: Ok, thanks to Katrin's suggestion, I'm getting some progress. I do get one row, but it's the one with the `role` number defined. Any way to preserve the one with the `NULL` role instead of the defined one?

Comment: use `SELECT * FROM (YOUR QUERY HERE) AS x GROUP BY x.email`  assuming email is unique for every user

Comment: Thanks @KatrinRaimond, yes the `email` is unique. I use it as an ID for every user. I'll try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since aggregate functions ignore null values, you can convert null to a number that can be extracted as min or max.
Assuming all your roles are greater than 0:

```
SELECT email, name, is_admin, enabled, nullif(min(coalesce(role, 0)), 0) as role
from
((
    SELECT DISTINCT
        gtfsws_users.email AS email,
        gtfsws_users.name AS name,
        gtfsws_users.is_admin AS is_admin,
        gtfsws_users.enabled AS enabled,
        gtfsws_repository_users.role AS role
    FROM
        gtfsws_users
    INNER JOIN
        gtfsws_repository_users
    ON
        gtfsws_users.email = gtfsws_repository_users.user_email
    WHERE
        gtfsws_repository_users.repository_id = '2'
)
UNION
(
    SELECT
        email,
        name,
        is_admin,
        enabled,
        null AS role
    FROM
        gtfsws_users
    WHERE
        is_admin = 1
)) as Q
GROUP BY email, name, is_admin, enabled
```